# How can I resize partitions using command line in my KVM

Tags: partitioning, disk, kvm-virtualization

I only have access to the server via a terminal and I can't use graphical tools.
I want to extend my /vda/vda3 from all free space of 150G.

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop1                       7:1    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop2                       7:2    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop3                       7:3    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop4                       7:4    0  40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20290
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
vda                       252:0    0   150G  0 disk 
├─vda1                    252:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─vda2                    252:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0    48G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    48G  0 lvm
```

My expect => /var/vda3 (148G)

[my disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3ffa.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. use GParted bootable USB for extend the partition (UI Mode).
2. boot back to ubuntu os.
3. extend by use lvextend command